# React update state from a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get values from a form and store it in state. Every time I follow a guide I get the following error (not to mention the guides are all in the class style react):

> "Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return
> statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

The component renders and I can even pass in a dummy value to the step.generalInfo.name and it shows up on the component.  However, as soon as I press a key into the input, boom error.  I think the error is in one of two places - either my handleChange() or the way I am trying to update the state as I am trying to get a value in an object inside another object. I am probably not destructuring or prop drilling correctly. Please help! Thanks!

App() renders the form below:

```js
function Form() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState({
    stage: 1,
    generalInfo: {
      name: "",
      batchSize: "",
      batchType: "",
      batchNumber: "",
      ibu: "",
      srm: "",
      abv: "",
      origionalGravity: "",
      finalGravity: "",
      brewingDate: "",
      dateSecondary: "",
      dateBottling: "",
    },
    ingredients: ["", "", ""],
    brewingNotes: "",
    hopsNotes: "",
    yeastNotes: "",
    fermentationNotes: "",
```

...More state and next/prev page functions...

```js
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setStep({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(step);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  switch (step.stage) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <StepOne
          step={step}
          next={next}
          prev={prev}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          setStep={setStep}
        />
      );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

StepOne Component is below:

```js
function StepOne({ step, next, prev, handleChange, setStep }) {
  const {
    name,
    batchSize,
    batchType,
    batchNumber,
    ibu,
    srm,
    abv,
    origionalGravity,
    finalGravity,
    brewingDate,
    dateSecondary,
    dateBottling,
  } = step.generalInfo;

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <h1>General Info</h1>
      <form>
        <div className="label-group">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
        <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StepOne;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its setStep within your handleChange method

```
setStep({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

useState doesn't merge in the same way this.setState does, therefor stage is getting overwritten and your switch statement doesn't return a render.

You instead need to pass a function to iterate state

```
setStep((state) => ({...state, generalInfo: {...state.generalInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}}))
```

But given the amount of nesting, the location of e.target.name would be verbose to find; you would benefit a lot from using useReducer instead of useState.

Comment: Thanks! That plus adding e.persist()l; into the handleChange fixed it! I can now update that nested state.  Makes sense how you explained it was overwriting the state and then it had nothing to render, aka that error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `handleChange` is incorrect, it remove all the field in state `step` except the current changed field.
That could lead to another component will crash if it is using data from state `step`

It should be

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setStep({ ...step, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); <= HERE
    console.log(step);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! You and the person above got me fixed by spreading the old state values into the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing handleChange was the key!

```js
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setStep((state) => ({
      ...state,
      generalInfo: { ...state.generalInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
    }));
    console.log(step);
  };
```